How to set a trigger in MySQL that prevents insertion but records the inserted value at the same time
The latest version of MySQL does not support trigger selection, but rolling back with signal will also affect the records inserted.So how to record the inserted data?
I tried to create a table to record the inserted data, but it would be rolled back.

how to record the inserted data? Use non-transactional (for example, MyISAM) table for recording.

If you use any programming language that interacts with the database, you could handle the insertion and recording of the data at the application level. For example, you could insert the data into the main table, then immediately record it in the secondary table within the same transaction. This way, if a rollback occurs, you still have the recorded data in the secondary table.
But always, it depends on the program needs and requirements.
In IT, the best way is to have different levels for different things, for easier maintenance.
So i would suggest think about solving the problem and implementing in the programming layer.
